# LG WebOS does not supports embedded subtitles

Tags: javascript, html5-video

LG WEBOS does not supports embedded subtitles only an external subtitle  As I know the only method to play videos on webOS is by using HTML5 video tag which doesn't support embedded subtitles. Please there are other methods to change  MKV, MP4 embedded subtitles?

Comment: You'll just have to extract the text from the video file bytes and generate some (dynamic) VTT subtitles from it. Open your video file in a **hex editor** to see the bytes and check where the subtitles are, then write JS code to go to same position (when file is loaded into a JS array) and extract the text.

Comment: Any update on this topic? I'm watching movies from a USB stick on my LG TV and I'd love to simply choose from the embedded subtitles within the video files.